How to hand Scroll Events with Radix UI, React
I am using Radux-ui's react-select and scrollable-area components, the idea is to build a select component that is able to detect when all the current data has all been scrolled, so that it can fetch more data, the problem is, I can't figure out how to target the scroll event to run a function, this is a simplified version of the code i have right now:
import * as SelectPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-select';
import * as ScrollArea from '@radix-ui/react-scroll-area';

const DropDownSelect = () => (

<Select.Root onValueChange={handleGroupChange}>
  <Select.Trigger className="flex-[.2]">
    <Select.Value placeholder="All groups" />
  </Select.Trigger>

  <Select.Portal>
    <Select.Content>
      <ScrollArea.Root type="auto">
        <Select.Viewport asChild>
          <ScrollArea.Viewport>
            
            {data.map((item) => (
              <Select.Item key={item} value={item}>
                {item}
              </Select.Item>
             ))}

          </ScrollArea.Viewport>
        </Select.Viewport>
      </ScrollArea.Root>
   </Select.Content>
</Select.Root>

)

i changed my styles but this should end up rendering something like this: 
any way for me to be able to handle scroll events on either the Scroll area or the Select component ?

npm i react-waypoint will helps you, know more here
